# why is my ember action not firing first time I click it?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I've got a view with a handlebars template that looks like this:

```
<a {{action 'totallyBogus'}}>bogus</a>
{{#each event in group.items}}
  <div class="event">
    <div class="details">
      <span class="name">
        <a {{action 'setActionSelectorEvent' event}}>{{event.prettyName}}</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

The controller has an action hash like this:

```
actions: {
  totallyBogus: function() {
    alert('got the totally bogus action');
  }, 
  setActionSelectorEvent: function(event) {
    alert('got the action');
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

The template is rendered perfectly. The problem is that the 'setActionSelectorEvent' action doesn't get called the first time you click the anchor. Every time thereafter, the action fires just fine. But the first time, something prevents the action from going through, and I don't see the alert.

However, the 'totallyBogus' action fires the first time you click it. Furthermore, if you click the 'totallyBogus' action, and *then* click the 'setActionSelectorEvent', it works fine.

What could possibly be causing this? I'm suspecting runloop shenangians, but don't know enough about Ember Internals to know exactly what's going on. I'm running Ember 1.7.1 and Ember-Data  1.0.0-beta.12

Comment: have you tried reproducing it on jsbin?

Comment: You're using a really old beta version of Ember. Is there a way for you to update to at least 1.2.0 stable and see if it's still an issue?

Comment: another good thought. I'll try it.

Comment: updated to Ember 1.7.1 (I had the version number wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying it with ember version 1.9.1 and it's working just fine:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xequce/1/edit?html,js,output

The one thing that I would do differently is have a `href='#'` even though the link is not going anywhere as in:

`<a href='#' {{action 'setActionSelectorEvent' event}}>{{event.prettyName}}</a>`

If you don't want the underline to show - you can always disable that with CSS.

Comment: ya, I tried that too. I think it has to do with the source of the items being iterated over in the template - it comes from a PromiseArray, and somehow maybe its not done doing its thing. I'm going to try upgrading my ember to see if that has any effect.

Comment: So I solved this issue - the property that is supplying the PromiseArray is dependent on a TextField, which has the focus set on didInsertElement. Removing the autofocus solved the first click problem. I'll update later with more details for posterity